# Click any menu-button to go back to one-pager AND scroll down to location

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm curious to know if there´s an option to go back from a page to one-pages and to
a specific location?

I have a webpage that is a one-pager with fixed menu - on that page is a button "apply for a job" that takes you to a external page but with the same fixed menu.

Can I make people click on the menu so it goes back to the one-pager an autoscroll down to
the location

Is this possible?

NOTABENE: I´m not looking for going back to the previus location - just any location that the user
will click on the menu (because it´s the same menu for application and the one pages (the whole site)

have a nice weekend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<a href='[Your URL] #[IDOfAnchorTagYouWantToScrollTo]'>[Link Text]</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a little [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dcncnood/).

The **ID** of an HTML element can be used later as an anchor.

```
<p id="article10">Article 10</p>
```

Here we scroll to an anchor within the same page/domain

```
<a href="#article10">Scroll to article 10</a>
```

This is how to access the anchor from an external page

```
<a href="www.example.com#article10">Scroll to article 10</a>
```

Have a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML_element#Anchor. It uses the same principle. The page is automatically scrolled down to the headline **Anchor** which has the ID **Anchor**.
For example Firebug reveals the following markup:

```
<span class="mw-headline" id="Anchor">Anchor</span>
```